How Install and run Microsoft Project on Ubuntu?
How to install and run Microsoft Project on Ubuntu ?

You can use the Wine package or a virtual machine

...but it doesn't seem to work very well (or at all) on Wine. See https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=6543

In general Microsoft does not make software for Ubuntu (Linux in general). You may install Windows in a virtual machine in Ubuntu and install any Microsoft software in Windows. This requires more RAM and CPU power than just using Ubuntu.
